# I have two functions, I want the second function to run after the first is complete with its animation

Tags: javascript

```
function firstRun() {
   rightBox.style.animation = "TextEffectMadeWithCSS 10s";
}

function secondRun() {
   rightBox.style.animation = "TextEffectMadeWithCSS 10s";
}
```

I dont want to use Jquery being that I am a beginner in javascript.
and i cannot at this level understand most Jquery syntax

Comment: Where are you calling these functions?

Comment: you'll need to understand JavaScript is asynchronous so to make sure the second function is called after the first you need the first to execute the second function after it's finished, this is known as a callback function, otherwise JavaScript will fire the first then fire the second and the second will execute before the first has finished.  All this being said, you did not show us any code to assist you further.

Comment: im calling the functions from the html page itself with <body onload="firstRun()">

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `animationend` events.

```
function firstRun(){
    rightBox.style.animation = "TextEffectMadeWithCSS 10s";
    rightBox.addEventListener('animationend', secondRun); //once it's finished.
}

function secondRun(){
    rightBox.style.animation = "TextEffectMadeWithCSS 10s";
    rightBox.removeEventListener('animationend', secondRun);
    //remove the listener so this doesn't loop.
}
```

Comment: Just wanted to post this. Here's a +1 and fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/bnjbzqbv/

Comment: thx for the jsfiddle example, i havent got it to work yet but i think your answer is the best and has put me on the right path

Comment: I guess it's not necessary to remove the listener, depending on what the function does. It will get executed a second time though. I'd just add it as a precaution.

Answer (score 0):

You could call the second function from the first:

```
var firstRun = function() {
    rightBox.style.animation = "TextEffectMadeWithCSS 10s";
    secondRun();
}

var secondRun = function() {
    rightBox.style.animation = "TextEffectMadeWithCSS 10s";
}
```